# Hive - How to display a warning message when the table has zero results

Tags: sql, hive

I need to create a query to print a warning message when the table is empty, but if it is empty, how can it print anything?
HIVE.hql:

```
select 
       x,y,count(*) 
from 
       table1
group by
       x,y
having
       count(*)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do:

```
select 'Oops! No rows!
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 0;
```

You can also do:

```
select 'Oops! No rows'
from t
having count(*) = 0;
```

However, I find `having` with no `group by` to be awkward.